# How to remove objects from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to remove an object from JSON array but is having a few issues. here is what I have right now.

```
{  
  "value":"In-plop",
  "no_delete":true,
  "disabled":null,
  "resource":"e48f8f",
  "email":"1"
 }
]';



foreach ($status as $key => $value) {
   if (in_array('Dispatched', $value)) {
    unset($status[$key]);
   }
  }
$status = json_encode($status);

echo $status;
```

I am trying to remove this entire object. I know my current code will only remove the value of the single object, but this is where I am stuck. The problem is that the object position is not static, it can be anywhere in the array. The only thing that is static is `value:Dispatched`. Any suggestions?

```
{  
  "value":"opuy",
  "no_delete":true,
  "disabled":null,
  "resource":"a382d1",
  "email":"1"
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have boolean `true` values in the array (that will match a type juggled true value such as string "Dispatched"), you need to pass `true` as the third parameter to `in_array()` for strict comparison.

Assuming you have run `json_decode()` and passed `true` for an array, just use strict comparison in `in_array()`:

```
   if (in_array('Dispatched', $value, true)) {
    unset($status[$key]);
   }
```

In this case, knowing the key I personally would use:

```
   if ($value['value'] === 'Dispatched') {
    unset($status[$key]);
   }
```

Comment: awesome man, i actually have json decode in my actual code but i guess when i made is shorter here i forgot to put that in. Thanks for the help. ,much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You should convert it first, remove the element and then re-encode.

```
$json = json_decode($status, true); //return an array
foreach($json as $key => $value) {
   if($value['value'] == 'Dispatched') {
    unset($json[$key]);
   }
}
$status = json_encode($json);
```

Comment: awesome man, i actually have json decode in my actual code but i guess when i made is shorter here i forgot to put that in. Thanks for the help. ,much appreciated.

Comment: @samjones39: This is a good answer, but does it tell you why your code doesn't work?

Comment: @abraCadaver, hey thanks for taking your time and explaining in your comments. i realize why my original coded did not work. your answer is good too. since i cannot accept both, i decided to accept  the first response.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to parse your json using json_decode, after that remove unused elements and on the end use json_encode to convert the array to string.

This code works:

```
$status='[  
{ 


  "value":"New",
  "no_delete":true,
  "disabled":null,
  "resource":"4eb2df",
  "email":null
},
{  
  "value":"Assigned",
  "no_delete":true,
  "disabled":null,
  "resource":"4c85b6",
  "email":1
},
{  
  "value":"Dispatched",
  "no_delete":true,
  "disabled":null,
  "resource":"a382d1",
  "email":"1"
},
{  
  "value":"Scheduled",
  "no_delete":true,
  "disabled":null,
  "resource":"75b4eb",
  "email":"1"
},
{  
  "value":"In-Progress",
  "no_delete":true,
  "disabled":null,
  "resource":"e48f8f",
  "email":"1"
 }
]';

$json = json_decode($status);
$result = [];

foreach($json as $key => $value) {
        if($value->value != "Dispatched") {
                $result[] = $value;
        }
}

print_r(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: awesome man, i actually have json decode in my actual code but i guess when i made is shorter here i forgot to put that in. Thanks for the help. ,much appreciated